# mysql: how to use the result of a stored procedure as a table/view in another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

i have a table - Adjustments - that looks like

id | employee_id | amount | earning/deduction

I need to query this table to get the total earnings and another query to get the total deductions.
the two queries will need a parameter - id.

i then need to create a 3rd query that will use the resulting table of those 2 queries. this 3rd query will also need the same parameter - id.

is it possible to call the 3rd query, passing the parameter - id, which will also be used by the 1st and 2nd queries.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks my friend, i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The first two can be done in one query.  I'm betting it's possible all three can be don in one.  But the answer is **yes**.

If you need more info, you have to give more info. Like all 3 queries.